# Exception and Logs Analysis frameworks or softwares

Tags: exception, logging, analysis

We have ASP.NET applications and supporting web services in production with lot of traffic.
It logs lot of service calls and Exceptions to MS Sql server.

We want to analyze the logs and exceptions, following are some use cases.

1. Monitor Success and Failures of calls to 3rd party services from Logs.
2. Generate graphical data from the logs.
   e.g AirPrice success 1300 times over a month.
       AirBooking failures 200 times over a month.
       comparison of above stats over the period of time.
3. Exceptions statistics :
   a. Percent increase in some Type of exceptions.
   b. spike in some type of exceptions
   c. occurence rate for some type of exceptions over a selectable period of time.

Is there any ready tool or framework which I can use to analyze such logs.
Or do I need to code such a thing myself.

Answer (score 0):

NewRelic (application performance monitoring service) is pretty damn good, though not cheap - check it out at http://newrelic.com/, and they have a free version.

Loggly is a simple logging service with a great and powerful dashboard for analyzing your logs and the price scales nicely with use.

Comment: It's probably a good idea to give a little more detail as to what NewRelic is.

Comment: And Loggly is sadly now quite expensive (over $1000 a year). There's nothing for free that does alerts as well. The nearest seems to be logz.io although I'm still on their 14 day trial. They seem too good to be true as even though I selected to join the free option, I seem to have been signed up to the professional package ($89 a month!) so will have to see what happens when my trial 14 days expires.